# How to set up a NodeJs Development environment with docker?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

i am trying to set up a nodejs development environment within docker, i also want hot reloading and source files to be in sync in both local and container, any help is appriciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good [article](https://hackernoon.com/a-better-way-to-develop-node-js-with-docker-cd29d3a0093) on hot reloading source files in a docker container for development environments.

Answer (score 0):

> source files to be in sync in both local and container

To achieve that you basically just need to mount your project directory to your container, as says [the official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/). For example:

```
docker run -v $PWD:/home/node node:alpine node index.js
```

What it does is:

- It will run container based on `node:alpine` image;
- `node index.js` command will be executed as the container is ready;
- The console output will come from the container to your host console, so you could debug things. If you don't want to see the output but return control to your console, you could use flag `-d`.
- And, the most valuable thing is that your current directory (`$PWD`) is fully synchronized with `/home/node/` directory of the container. Any file update will be immediately represented at your container files.

> I also want hot reloading

It depends on the approach you are using to serve your application.

For example, you could use [Webpack dev server](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/) with a hot reload setting. After that, all you need to map a port to your webpack dev server's port.

```
docker run \
  -v $PWD:/home/node \
  -p 8080:8080 \
  node:alpine \
  webpack-dev-server \
    --host 0.0.0.0 \
    --port 8080
```